# how to remove WhiteSpaces in telegram instant view API?

Tags: xpath, xquery, telegram

I am trying to setup a Telegram  Instant View for a website.
this website has a lot of empty

tags that i don't know how to remove them.

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">    &nbsp;</p>
```

i want to find a way to remove and get rid of these kind of

tags

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove `&nbsp;` just use `@replace` function:

```ml
@replace("\u00a0", ""): //nodes/text()
```

If you want to remove tags with spaces, call `@remove` and pass a predicate, that selects empty nodes after space normalization.

```
@remove: //nodes[not(  normalize-space(text())  )]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it Ehasn:

First replace all " " content with sample string like "null-tag" the remove them using this code:

```
@replace("\u00a0", "null-tag"): //p
@remove: //p[.="null-tag"]
```

Note that it might change some contents check some pages to make sure it work fine for you.